Computational complexity of arithmetic sentences over classical theories
Below, I use the term "tracker" rather than "realizer" since I'm not requiring the relevant objects to be computable.
Define the relation "$f$ tracks $\varphi$" for $f:\omega\rightarrow\omega$ and $\varphi$ a sentence in the language of arithmetic (with no implications or non-atomic negations) by recursion as follows:

For $\varphi$ literal, $f$ tracks $\varphi$ iff $\mathbb{N}\models\varphi$.

For $\varphi\equiv\psi\wedge\theta$, $f$ tracks $\varphi$ iff $\lambda x.f(2x)$ tracks $\psi$ and $\lambda x. f(2x+1)$ tracks $\theta$.

For $\varphi\equiv\psi\vee\theta$, $f$ tracks $\varphi$ iff EITHER $f(0)=0$ and $\lambda x. f(x+1)$ tracks $\psi$, OR $f(0)=1$ and $\lambda x.f(x+1)$ tracks $\theta$.

For $\varphi\equiv\exists x\psi(x)$, $f$ tracks $\varphi$ iff $\lambda x.f(x+1)$ tracks $\psi(\underline{f(0)})$ (where $\underline{n}$ is the numeral standing for $n$).

For $\varphi\equiv\forall x\psi(x)$, $f$ tracks $\varphi$ iff for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the function $\lambda x. f(\langle n,x\rangle)$ tracks $\psi(\underline{n})$ (where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is some "reasonable" pairing function).


Note that a sentence is trackable iff it is true in $\mathbb{N}$, so the notion above has no constructive content unless we pay attention to the complexities of the trackers.
Now for a (classical!) theory $T$ in the language of arithmetic, let the tracking spectrum of $\varphi$ over $T$ be the set of Turing degrees computing functions which track some $T$-equivalent of $\varphi$: $$\mathsf{TS}_T(\varphi)=\{{\bf d}\in\mathscr{D}: \exists \psi\dashv\vdash_T\varphi, \exists f\in{\bf d}\mbox{ tracking }\psi\}.$$ Of course, if $T$ is strong enough (and $\varphi$ is true) then $\mathsf{TS}_T(\varphi)$ is just the set of all Turing degrees, $\mathscr{D}$. My first question is what happens when $T$ doesn't prove $\varphi$ but is still a "reasonable improvement" on the empty theory. To give a concrete example:

What is the tracking spectrum over $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ of the sentence "There exists a maximal c.e. set"? (Over the empty theory, the tracking spectrum is clearly the cone above ${\bf 0''}$.)

The theory $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ is known to not prove the existence of a maximal c.e. set (even $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_2$ isn't enough); however, it is strong enough to prove the equivalence of any "reasonable" formalizations of this principle, so we can get away with natural language here. If another "infinite-injury-type" principle would make things easier here I'm happy to use it instead (e.g. "There is a high Turing degree"). My guess is that the answer is just "The cone above ${\bf 0''}$" again, but I don't see how to prove that.

I have this trivial observation. We have sentences that are essentially $\Pi_n$ over given theories (in the sense of not having equivalent $\Sigma_n$-sentences). Canonical example of essentially $\Pi_n$-sentence over $T$ is the reflection principle $\mathsf{RFN}{\Pi_n}(T)$. Over $\mathsf{PA}$, the $\Pi{n+2}$-sentence "$f$ is an index of $0^{(n)}$-recursive function that tracks $\varphi$" implies $\varphi$. Thus, for sound extensions of $\mathsf{PA}$ the spectrum of true essentially $\Pi_{n+3}$ sentences always includes upper cone of $0^{(n+1)}$ and excludes lower cone of $0^{(n)}$.
